# JSP helper class for printing content

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a question on code reuse in JSP. I have a JSP page `example.jsp` that issues a call to a database and gets the results. I have a java class `HelperClass.java` that accepts a record and prints out the different fields

```
response.getWriter().println
```

Now my JSP page has HTML as well and the problem is the content printed out by the HelperClass appears before the content in the JSP page. E.g.

```
<body>
    This is the first line <br/>
    HelperClass.printdata("second line"); 
</body>
```

output is

```
secondline This is the first line
```

Is this a known issue. What is the best way to design an `HelperClass` for a JSP page that prints content out to the page. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do not use a "HelperClass to print data". This makes no sense. There you have EL for.

```
${bean.property}
```

That's all. Use a servlet to control, preprocess and postprocess requests. Use taglibs (e.g. JSTL) and EL to access and display backend data.

Here's a basic kickoff example of a Servlet which preprocesses the request before display in JSP:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Person> persons = personDAO.list(); // Get list of persons from DB.
    request.setAttribute("persons", persons); // So it's available as `${persons}` in EL.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/persons.jsp").forward(request, response); // Forward to JSP for display.
}
```

Here, the `Person` is just a Javabean class which represents a real world entity.

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Integer age;
    // Add/generate getters and setters here.
}
```

The `PersonDAO#list()` method just returns a `List` of `Person` objects from the DB:

```
public List<Person> list() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement("SELECT id, name, email, age FROM person");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
            person.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            person.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
            person.setAge(resultSet.getInteger("age"));
            persons.add(person);
        }
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    return persons;
}
```

Map the servlet in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of `/persons`. The JSP is hidden in `/WEB-INF` so that nobody can access it directly without requesting the servlet first (else one would get an empty table).

Now, here's how `persons.jsp` look like, it uses [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`) [`c:forEach`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) to iterate over a `List` and it uses EL to access the backend data and bean properties. The servlet has put the `List<Person>` as request attribute with name `persons` so that it's available by `${persons}` in EL. Each iteration in `c:forEach` gives a `Person` instance back, so that you can display their proeprties with EL.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

...

<table>
    <c:forEach items="${persons}" var="person">
        <tr>
            <td>${person.name}</td>
            <td>${person.email}</td>
            <td>${person.age}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Call it by http://example.com/contextname/persons. That's all. No need for a "HelperClass to print data" ;) To learn more about JSTL, check [Java EE tutorial part II chapter 7](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) and to learn more about EL, check [Java EE tutorial part II chapter 5](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html). To learn more about stuff behind PersonDAO, check [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will look into JSTL and EL. 
Thanks again.