# Displaying database result in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a controller servlet which forward the request to the model servlet.Now when the model gets the results from the database, I am forwarding it to the jsp.I am not sure what to write in the jsp because it need to show a table of customerList.here is part of my model servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    Connection connection = getDatabaseConnection();
    request.setAttribute("customerList", getCustomerList(connection));
    closeDatabaseConnection(connection);
}

private Vector<Customer> getCustomerList(Connection con)
{
    String sqlStr =
            "SELECT * " +
            "FROM Customer " +
            "ORDER BY Name";
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Vector<Customer> customers = new Vector<Customer>();

    try
    {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
            customer.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
            customer.setAddress(rs.getString("Address"));

            customers.add(customer);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        return customers;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`c:forEach`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag. If your servletcontainer doesn't support it (e.g. Tomcat), then you need to drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Then declare the [JSTL core taglib](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) in top of JSP page as per its documentation.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Then you can use any of the JSTL core tags in the JSP. You've put a `Vector<Customer>` (eek, a legacy class .. rather use `List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>()` instead) in the request scope with the attribute name `customerList`. So it's available by `${customerList}` in EL. Feed it to the `items` attribute of `<c:forEach>` and render a `<table>` accordingly.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${customerList}" var="customer">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${customer.id}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${customer.name}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${customer.address}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The `<c:out>` is by the way not necessary, but useful if it concerns user-controlled input since it prevents XSS attacks.

That said, your JDBC part can be done better. It's still sensitive to resource leaking in case of exceptions.

#### See also:

- [Displaying multiple database records in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831053/displaying-multiple-records-by-using-resultset)
- [JSP helper class for printing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280034/jsp-helper-class-for-printing-content)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet)