# how to retrieve data from a db in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have got a jsp page which has 5 columns and 12 rows .I have to retrieve data in such a way that the first record fetched should go in to first row,,,,the second in second row.....How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying database result in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196197/displaying-database-result-in-jsp)

Answer (score 1):

connect to DB in servlet fetch the data using [`JDBC`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) and set required data to request/session/application scope as needed and forward the request to view (jsp)

**Also See**

- [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [design-patterns-web-based-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/)

Answer (score 1):

Start from [Basic JSP Sample : Database Access - JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/jsps/ojsp/dbaccessjdbc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with the above - in any serious production application database should happen in Java/JDBC in a proper controller, and not in the view (JSP).

But, sometimes it makes sense to use JSTL's SQL capabilities, check out a good JSTL primer here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0520/index.html

Some relevant code:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="dataSrc"
    url="jdbc:mysql:///taglib" driver="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
    user="admin" password="secret"/>
    <sql:query var="queryResults" dataSource="${dataSrc}">
  select * from blog group by created desc limit ?
  <sql:param value="${6}"/></sql:query>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
  </tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${queryResults.rows}">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.created}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.title}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.author}"/></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```