# ResultSet to Collection

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I want to put ResultSet data into something i can forward to a JSP from a Servlet. Should i be looking into getObject() from the ResultSet interface to make a java List? Is there an easier way?

Comment: This question looks pretty much like yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384189/how-do-i-make-a-java-resultset-available-in-my-jsp

Comment: So an ArrayList of Arraylists would be my best option?

Comment: No, that isn't what the accepted answer in the given link is recommending. Here are another duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831053/displaying-multiple-records-by-using-resultset/1832524#1832524 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280034/jsp-helper-class-for-printing-content/2280358#2280358

Answer (score 1):

Apache [commons-dbutils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) can be used to easily do this

Answer (score 1):

use bean classes and set the data accordingly in each bean object. Put bean objects into the `Arraylist` object and set it into the request object.